# Extjs notification popup with Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, notifications, popup, sencha-architect

I want to create a notification drop down menu like the one on Facebook. I'm getting data using signalR.

For the design, I couldn't find a perfect control. I tried using `menu dropdown` but it does not look good. Can anyone suggest or give me a sample code for notification drop down using Sencha Architect?

I want it to look similar to this:

[image: Notification dropdown]

Comment: Are you using Sencha Touch?

Comment: no. im using extjs with sencha architect.

Comment: I dont know any suitable component out-of-the-box, but you can crate custom component based on [`Ext.form.field.Picker`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker).

Comment: Include info from comments, improve grammar

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "showBy" method to show the panel below the button, here's the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/19cc

"showBy" details here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-showBy